# Stumped on the dimensions of the logo to be placed on the various DPI screen versions while designing Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns

I am trying to design an android app and feel stumped on the dimensions of the logo to be placed on the various DPI screen versions and other scenarios possible. Please suggest what should be the size of logo per DPI screen. I am using attached image as reference for other design specifications such as icons and bar size.

1. I am trying to create a launcher icon
2. Developer has requested different logo size versions as per the
       screen DPI.
3. What should be the size of the correct size of the logo max and min
       to be placed on any screen of the app? Is it completely up to the designer?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Using this image for rest of the icons size details.]

**There are commonly two ways to target all screen DPIs.**

1. Easiest way - Make all images to Extra High or Extra Extra High DPI.
2. **Safe way - Make all images for every single DPI.**

Now my question is what size should my logo be in order to be able to make **Make all images for every single DPI.**

Hope this help to understand.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Where are you trying to put the logo? Are you creating a launcher icon?

Comment: Just edited the question to include specification.

Comment: This tool might be useful for what you need: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: I have already gone through this. It does not look very attractive, as half of the space remains empty. Any other options? and moreover it leaves me with the problem of providing developer diff sizes of logo as per DPI versions.

Comment: I think you may be getting confused between DPI (dots per inch) and DIP (density independent pixels). Download the zip file from the asset studio and you will see exactly what is required.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can change the asset studio settings so it doesn't change the colour of the logo.

Comment: I just did and it worked. Although  It does not look very attractive, as half of the space remains empty. Any other options? and moreover it leaves me with the problem of providing developer diff sizes of logo as per DPI versions.

Comment: As I already said, I don't think you need to deal with DPI in the way you think you do. There is a padding setting in the asset studio which you can reduce to zero.

Comment: I got the launch icons perfectly. Thanks. but I also ned help with the second part such as Safe way - Make all images for every single DPI.

Now my question is what size should my logo be in order to be able to make Make all images for every single DPI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88735/discussion-between-intrications-and-abhishekdwivedi).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did a bit more research and asked around and finally found the solutions.

While every tutorial out the there specifies the ratio to resize the images to as per DPI, But how to actually do it was proving to be quite difficult for a novice me.

Then used [PNG Express](http://www.pngexpress.com/) and rest was all easy. They provided every image as per the developer specified ratio. While this tool is not free and requires first hand payment, please update if there's any better tool.

I am sorry if I wasn't very clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a launcher icon then the sizes in pixels are clearly defined in the image you have posted.

To get started you should try loading the logo into the Android Asset Studio at:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

This may give you good enough results to use. Otherwise, you can at least see what icon sizes are required and what folder layout is required by Android.